# SpamAssassin wierd logging problem

Tags: spamassassin

I have a wierd problem with SpamAssassin loggin a problem to mail.log
Sometimes, SpamAssassin complains about "internal error, python traceback seen in response".

What can I do to resolve this problem ?

Example log:

```
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamc[365495]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection timed out
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamc[365494]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection timed out
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamc[365495]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection timed out
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamc[365494]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection timed out
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:53516 to port 783, fd 6
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:53518 to port 783, fd 6
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: spamd: setuid to debian-spamd succeeded
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: spamd: setuid to debian-spamd succeeded
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: spamd: processing message <0841f372ef0cf2acc8c14eb6c0f1cf89@newsletter.decitit.com> for debian-spamd:125
Jan 10 11:06:31 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: spamd: processing message <0841f372ef0cf2acc8c14eb6c0f1cf89@newsletter.decitit.com> for debian-spamd:125
Jan 10 11:06:33 scpej-hga spamd[365524]: util: setuid: ruid=125 euid=125 rgid=135 135 egid=135 135 
Jan 10 11:06:33 scpej-hga spamd[365523]: util: setuid: ruid=125 euid=125 rgid=135 135 egid=135 135 
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: internal error, python traceback seen in response
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: internal error, python traceback seen in response
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: spamd: clean message (4.1/5.0) for debian-spamd:125 in 3.8 seconds, 12458 bytes.
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350070]: spamd: result: . 4 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_51_100,RAZOR2_CHECK,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=3.8,size=12458,user=debian-spamd,uid=125,required_score=5.0,rhost=127.0.0.1,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=53516,mid=<0841f372ef0cf2acc8c14eb6c0f1cf89@newsletter.decitit.com>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: spamd: clean message (4.1/5.0) for debian-spamd:125 in 3.8 seconds, 12458 bytes.
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350071]: spamd: result: . 4 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_51_100,RAZOR2_CHECK,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=3.8,size=12458,user=debian-spamd,uid=125,required_score=5.0,rhost=127.0.0.1,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=53518,mid=<0841f372ef0cf2acc8c14eb6c0f1cf89@newsletter.decitit.com>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350039]: prefork: child states: IB
Jan 10 11:06:34 scpej-hga spamd[350039]: prefork: child states: II
```

Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS running SpamAssassin 3.4.4-1ubuntu1.

Thank you !

Comment: I have a very similar error. DId you ever figure this out?